# Validation during a loop?

Tags: java

I have a program where a user enters the numbers 1, 2 or 3. Depending on the number the user has enter their grades for that year; e.g

User enters 2
59
39

BUT how would i write a loop that validates the input meaning it cannot be over 100 or under 0.

I would give code but I literally don't know where to start.

do have a loop that inputs the grades into an arraylist

```
grades.clear();
for(int i = 0; i <= level; i++){
    System.out.println("Please enter your grade for level " + i);
    level1 = s.nextInt();
    grades.add((double) level1);
}
```

Is ther anyway I could incorporate that validation into that loop?
Thanks

Comment: use condition if else

Comment: but i want it to loop around until a value between 0 and 100 is entered, i dont think that would do it. @FastSnail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `while` cycle here:

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= level; i++){
        level1 = -1;
        while (level1 < 0 || level1 > 100) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your grade for level " + i);
            level1 = s.nextInt();
        }
        grades.add((double) level1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this method

```
public static int loopToValidate(Scanner s) {
    int i = 0;
    for (;;) {
        i = s.nextInt();
        if (i >= 0 && i <= 100) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter your grade for level it should be greater than 0 and less than 100");
            loopToValidate(s);
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

In your for loop make this change.

`for(int i = 0; i <= level; i++){
    System.out.println("Please enter your grade for level " + i);
    level1 = loopToValidate(s);
    grades.add(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(level1)));
}`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below:

```
grades.clear();
for(int i = 0; i <= level; i++){
    System.out.println("Please enter your grade for level " + i);
    level1 = s.nextInt();
    if (level1 < 0 || level1 > 100) {
        i--;
        //print invalid input?
        continue;
    }
    grades.add((double) level1);
}
```